# I need to put await asynchronous for waiting response while my static main had [STAThread]

Tags: c#

I want to wait unlit my one process is done after one process done than start new one.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{            
    if (!SkipUpdate)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UpdaterURL))
            Start(AppSettings.UpdaterURL);
        else
        {
            DialogUtil.Notify("AIMM is unable to contact the server at this time. Please try again later.");
            return;
        }
    }
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

As per my code i want to put start method in await.
because once start method process done only after that Run method call.

Comment: You haven't asked a question or explained what's going right or wrong with your code. Perhaps you should read [ask] and [mcve]?

Comment: So what's keeping you from declaring your main method as `async Task` instead of `void`?